# Two floating divs side by side, same height

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 divs in a larger div must equal the same height… but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222695/2-divs-in-a-larger-div-must-equal-the-same-height-but-how)

I'm having trouble auto setting the height of my containerLeft div (red background) the same height as my containerRight div.  I specifically want this to stay a fluid grid.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222695/2-divs-in-a-larger-div-must-equal-the-same-height-but-how/10222806#10222806

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know that one of the two columns is always going to be taller than the other, then you can do something like this:

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/2/)

Just give `position: absolute` to the shorter column and make it stretch from `top: 0` to `bottom: 0`.

**HTML**:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="containerLeft">
        <h2>1.</h2>
        <p>First, let's play a video.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="containerRight">
        <img src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/michael-headshot-red.jpg?w=288" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**:

```
.container { position: relative; }
.containerLeft { /* shorter column */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: crimson;
}
.containerRight { /* taller column */
    margin: 0 0 0 42%;
    width: 58%;
    background: dodgerblue;
}​
```

---

If you don't know for sure which one of them is going to be taller, then you can *simulate* the fact that they are of equal `height` by using a background [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient) on their parent.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/3/)

HTML is the same, **CSS** becomes:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, crimson 42%, dodgerblue 42%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, crimson 42%, dodgerblue 42%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, crimson 42%, dodgerblue 42%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, crimson 42%, dodgerblue 42%);
}
.containerLeft, .containerRight { float: left; }
.containerLeft {
    width:38%;
    padding: 2%;
}
.containerRight { width: 58%; }​
```

---

However, [CSS gradients don't work in IE9 and older](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), so if you want a solution for IE8+, then you can try this

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/4/)

which uses [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::before) and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::after) [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.container:before,.container:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    content: '';
}
.container:before {
    left: 0;
    width: 42%;
    background: crimson;
}
.container:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 58%;
    background: dodgerblue;
}
.containerLeft, .containerRight { float: left; }
.containerLeft {
    z-index: 2;
    width:38%;
    padding: 2%;
}
.containerRight { width: 58%; }​
```

Comment: +1: Really dig the first solution. Nice one Ana.

Comment: thanks Ana.  Question on your first solution.  There's a little space on the bottom, underneath the pic (right column).  Anyway we can get rid of that.   Other than that, thank you!

Comment: ### Follow-up answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558268/two-floating-divs-side-by-side-same-height-follow-up

Answer (score 1):

The problem with floating divs is that they are taken out of the "normal flow". that means the CSS interpreter has no idea about the size of the parent, so setting the height cannot be done "automatically", you will have to set a height manually.

This update to your fiddle should make things clear: http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can clip the bottom off one column: http://jsfiddle.net/gtGjY/

I added:

```
.containerLeft {
    padding-bottom: 1005px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
.outer { overflow: hidden; } /* div around both columns */

.containerRight img {
    display: block;
}​
```