# Two floating divs side by side, same height (follow up)

Tags: html, css

My previous question was answered here: [Two floating divs side by side, same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556856/two-floating-divs-side-by-side-same-height/12557058#12557058)

My problem:  Someone supplied an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7ufg/18/

How can I remove the extra space below the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add vertical-align:top to your img rule:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;   
    vertical-align:top;
}
​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s7ufg/20/)**

Answer (score 4):

`display:block;` to the image solve it

```
img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;   
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/hpvBD/)**